# How to make matplotlib load quicker?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

This code takes an ungodly amount of time to run ~33 minutes, how can i make it quicker.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

points = [[x, y, z] for x in range(256) for y in range(256) for z in range(256)]
# --- ~11.32s ---
# rgb length = 16777216

ax.scatter([x[0] for x in points], [y[1] for y in points], [z[2] for z in points],
           color=[[color[0] / 255, color[1] / 255, color[2] / 255] for color in points])
# --- ~11m ---

plt.show()
# --- ~12m ---
```

[image]

edit:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

every_point = [[x, y, z] for x in range(256) for y in range(256) for z in range(256)]
# rgb length = 16777216

points = [loc for loc in every_point if 255 in loc or 0 in loc]
# rgb length = 390152
# removed all unnecessary "below skin" points. only points visible will be loaded

ax.scatter([x[0] for x in points], [y[1] for y in points], [z[2] for z in points],
           color=[[color[0] / 255, color[1] / 255, color[2] / 255] for color in points])

plt.show()
# --- 46s ---
```

This code made it almost 50 times quicker, about 46 seconds to completely load up image. The code is still fairly slow when it comes to rotating the image.

Comment: You are running 4 iterations over the 16.7M items `points` and then it needs to be processed. Thats going to take some time. Try with less data.

Comment: Klaus D. I'm intentionaly using 16.7M ```points```, it's the amount of colors makable through rgb. I was wondering if there were some ways of making the code a bit faster. I'm curently using pycharm, are there any software modifications i could add to speed up proccesing time.

Comment: I added an edit to the original code but its still pretty slow when rotating image.

Comment: You are aware that you will only be able to see the _outer scatter points_ with that point density anyhow? Why not simply plot this as a 3d surface? Also think about whether you will actually be able to visually discern a 24bit rgb cube from e.g. a 15bit rgb cube with a slightly larger scatter point size?!

Comment: I removed all unnecessary points, but what are the 15bit and 24bit rgb cube you're talking about